# TypeError: $.bez is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi I'm trying to use AngularJs animation in my project but it doesn't apply as expected and displays the error message:

> **TypeError:** $.bez is not a function and TypeError: jQuery(...).yiiactiveform is not a function

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I assume bez is a class name, therefore you should use `$('.bez')`

Comment: $.bez refers to a js plugin that allows devs to implement easing functions, exactly like the ones used in CSS, into the jQuery animate() library. I'm having this same issue. Link to the library below: Transitions.https://github.com/gre/bezier-easing